# Trace / alert /synch /monitor KAFKA data transfer

Tags: database, apache-kafka, monitoring, database-replication, micrometer-tracing

We have KAFKA implemented and transferring data from source database to another destination database frequently.
Here we need to ensure data is consistent between these database systems.
How do we verify data consistency between the databases and monitor it if any delay in the producer(source) side or KAFKA side or consumer (destination) side, alert if any failures in the data transfer events.
How to trace in case events missed in consumer side?
How to automate data synch if in case stuck for some issues.

Regards
Mohan

Due to security reasons these two databases cannot be connected directly . So,need solution without using the tools connecting databases directly.

Comment: Kafka has tools for at least consumer lag already. For data consistency, Kafka has no builtin solution for this, and asking for libraries/tools like this is considered off topic per [help]